# codeigniter php

Tags: sql

Имеется такой код:

```
<?php
$this->db->where("user_name","admin2");
$query = $this->db->get("works");
$data = $query->result();
if(count($data) > 0) {
    foreach($query as $row) {
    echo $row->title;
    }
}
?>
```

выводит ошибку:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: mysqli::$title
Filename: views/site.php
Line Number: 7
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

В foreach вы наверное хотели использовать результат запроса

```
foreach($data as $row) {
```